# How to match Jtextfield value with a pattern?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to validate Student Id according to this format : SLIOP-S-001 OR 
SLIOP-WS-1004.
I tried the below code and it is not working. Can someone assistance me to find the mistake in the code? Thanks.

```
 private void studentidKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
   char s=evt.getKeyChar();

    String sid = "^[SLIOP]+[-]+[S||WS]+[-]+[0-9]{6}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sid);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String.valueOf(s));

    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        evt.consume();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valid ID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) is not really correct to match your inputs

Here is what it could look like

```
String sid = "^SLIOP-(S|WS)-(\\d)+$";
```

- `^` : Begin of the string
- `SLIOP-` : Matches `SLIOP-` Litterally
- `(S|WS)` : Matches either one of `S` or `WS`
- `-` : Matches `-` Litterally
- `(\\d)+` : Finds multiple numbers in a row
- `$` : End of string

Comment: @lakshi It works for me, try to work on your inputs. Try trimming them for example.

Answer (score 2):

You check if a single char can match with an entire pattern, it simply cannot work this way, you need to check the entire `String` not a single character.